# Tomcat application to spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

we have old tomcat application in our project. I like to change it to spring boot for easing my development. but I don't know the way. Will someone helps me out, how to do that

Comment: StackOverflow is not the place to ask for general programming help. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: In the meanwhile start with https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

Answer (score 0):

Actually they are two different things.
You can have a Tomcat server with Spring Boot framework.
If you want to get this server setted with Spring Boot, just get a look in this link:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-configure-tomcat